Why not John Mark the main writer of letter to Hebrews?
I wrote main author because the other authors are Timothy and Luke.

Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for joining our group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.  Please nominate a specific passage of the Bible to ask about.  The author of Hebrews is not known.

I agree that it could be. But we cannot be dogmatic as the writer fails to identify himself that Christ might be seen as the author, sent to the Jews initially. (Paul to the Gentiles.) Marks's gospel is headed in regard to the Messenger of the Covenant (Malachi quoted in the opening verses) which is very much in keeping with the 'Apostle' and High Priest of our calling. Up-voted but you need to focus on a text as the site requires.
